# QGIS print layout: creating a shadow arroud a frame for legend at only specific sides

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Currently I am trying to build a drop shadow for two specific sides of legend, the thing is I do not seem to find the option for this anywhere in the item menu of the legend. Not to mention it has to essentially look like this, a shadow to the right and bottom side 1.5mm thick.

[image]

**Also of note the Legend height and width updates automatically based on what is in the map view of the layer, so it constantly changes in width and height. Drawing another border on the legend then is not an option because I would have to adjust this border each and every time and for basicly a template that is going to be used for potentially 63 times, that is a bit of double work.**

Comment: Would it be a viable option to create a legend with a fixed size large enough for all of your maps? We're working with this, using a standard layout for all maps.

Comment: This was thought of at first but the problem is that each map or rather group of maps sometimes have only one legend item, or too much legend items to fit on the map. That is the reason why we decided that the legend will only contain items that are in view based on the scale. To prevent some extra work and only use as few as templates as possible. The only thing thats needs to be adjusted is the legend which layers relevant