# QGIS Layout Print Composer: getting the height (etc.) variable of a certain layout item

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Currently I am drawing two polygons that are supposed to be the "shadow" of legend since apparently there is no shadow on frame option.

**Yes this question is related to this one [QGIS print layout: creating a shadow arroud a frame for legend at only specific sides](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372983/qgis-print-layout-creating-a-shadow-arroud-a-frame-for-legend-at-only-specific), but considering the topic is different I am asking a new one here.**
*For now I am just testing it with one.*

The problem is however that the height and width of the Legend is dynamic depending on what gets into it, so to sure the polygons also adapt to the legend, I will be giving them the height and width values of the legend plus a certain marge. Now in theory I should be using this formula because my Item Id of the Legend is Legend.

```
map_get(item_variables( 'Legend' ), 'height')
```

However the problem is that this does not actually work. Not to mention I need to add some extra values like 0.3 (because of the frame size of the legend) so in theory I should also do this:

```
map_get(item_variables( 'Legend' ), 'height') + 0.3
```

**What am I doing wrong here because when the legend auto adapts the polygon does not adapt?**

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, I didn't specifically have a look at the legend item. Still, the hint persists: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#expression-variables - if your variable ain't there, it's hard to grab.

Comment: Yeah the variable is not there. Guess I have to drop that shadow part.